# Print photo Pixel by Pixel, with CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css

I was thinking about if it would take less space if you would print out the a whole image with CSS and HTML (Pixel by Pixel). I am not talking about `background-image` or something like that, I am talking about something like this

```
<div style="height:1px, width:1px, background-color: black;" >
<div style="height:1px, width:1px, background-color: red;" >
<div style="height:1px, width:1px, background-color: blue;" >
```

And if you would keep going an make a whole photo with CSS pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. That would be *much* larger than an image file.

Your example uses 50 to 60 bytes of HTML for each pixel in the image. With some optimization, this could potentially be brought down to perhaps 30 bytes.

By comparison, an *uncompressed* image file (e.g, [Windows BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)) uses about 4 bytes of data for each pixel. Compressed formats like PNG and JPEG are even smaller, typically well under one byte per pixel.